# How to use capture groups in GoLang?

Tags: regex, go, capture-group

I need to get Golang logs using regex but the output of the regex is incorrect for the "msg" capture group. I have this function here to extract log statements from the contents of a file:

```
func extractLogStatements(content string) []LogStatement {
    logPattern := `flog\.(?P<sev>.*?)\(\s*flog.(?P<type>.*?),\s*("|fmt.Sprintf\(")(?P<msg>.*?)"`

    re := regexp.MustCompile(logPattern)
    matches := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(content, -1)

    logStatements := make([]LogStatement, 0, len(matches))
    for _, match := range matches {
        statement := LogStatement{
            Sev:  match[1],
            Type: match[2],
            Msg:  match[3],
        }
        logStatements = append(logStatements, statement)
    }

    return logStatements
}
```

Everything works correctly except the regex pattern on the first line in the function is not capturing the correct values for the capture groups, even though when I tested on an online regex parser it worked fine.

Here are some examples of the logs I've been testing on:

```
flog.Info(flog.Application, fmt.Sprintf("unable to translate address for config: %v", err))

flog.Info(flog.Application, "unable to translate address for config")

flog.Info(flog.Application, fmt.Sprintf("Test 1"),
    lm.CrKind, objectType,
    lm.CrName, crName,
    lm.AppNS, namespace)
```

For the first log example, it should extract "Info" ("sev" capture group), "Application" ("type" capture group), and "unable to translate address for config: %v" ("msg" capture group). When I output to json I get:

```
[
    {
        "sev": "Info",
        "type": "Application",
        "msg": "fmt.Sprintf(\""
    },
    {
        "sev": "Info",
        "type": "Application",
        "msg": "fmt.Sprintf(\""
    },
    {
        "sev": "Info",
        "type": "Application",
        "msg": "fmt.Sprintf(\""
    },
]
```

So it's capturing the "sev" and "type" capture groups correctly but for the "msg" it's capturing "fmt.Sprintf("" when it should be getting "unable to translate address for config: %v".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match[3]` stores the value for the group `("|fmt.Sprintf\(")`. If you don't want to capture it, use `?:` to turn it into a non-capturing group.

```
(?:"|fmt.Sprintf\(")
```

Since all the values you want are captured by **named capture groups**, another solution is to reference them by name:

```golang
for _, match := range matches {
    statement := LogStatement{
        Sev:  match[re.SubexpIndex("sev")],
        Type: match[re.SubexpIndex("type")],
        Msg:  match[re.SubexpIndex("msg")],
    }
    logStatements = append(logStatements, statement)
}
```